# Probability of selecting 2 defective bulbs

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

A box contains 14 bulbs of which 2 are defective. Two bulbs are taken at
random one-by-one without replacement. What is the probability that both bulbs are
defective?

The answer I've come up with is 7C1*7C6/14C7 which is roughly 0.01427. However, I have a feeling this isn't correct. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The probability the first one is defective is $\frac 2{14}$...conditioned on the first being defective, the probability that the second is also defective is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, and you have good thinking, but you're not there yet.

Let's think about this logically.  What is the probability that the first bulb you pick is defective? $2/14$ (reduced to $1/7$).  There are 2 defective bulbs and 14 possible bulbs.

So the probability you pick 1 defective bulb on the first try is 1/7, and we have that established.  The probability you pick another defective bulb would be $(2-1)/(14-1)$, which can be reduced to $1/13$.

If you multiply both of these things together, you'll get the answer.  The answer is $(1*1)/(13*7)$, which is equivalent to $1/91$, which doesn't reduce.

In conclusion, the answer is **1/91**.

Answer (score 1):

P(both defective)=P(first defective)*P(second defective, given the first defective)
P(AB)=P(A)*P(A|B)
First defective: (2/14)
P(second defective|given the first was defective)= ?

Multiply, done.

Comment: I did a similar thing above.  $P(A|B)$=1/13, so you would get $(2*1)/(14*13)$ --> $(2/182)$ --> $(1/91)$.

Comment: That's right. good job.

Comment: Up vote my thing if it was helpful

Comment: Please do the same for me.  It was indeed helpful.